# Geometrically, what does raising a real number to a complex number do on the complex plane?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know the formula to raise a real number to a complex number:
 $a^{b+ic}=a^b\cdot(\cos(b \ln a) + i\sin(b \ln a))$ 
but I don't understand how it's derived. I know what the trig functions are doing but I'm not quite understanding what the natural log is doing and how this relationship transforms on the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation of $a^{b+ic}$ comes from Euler's Identity: $$a^{b+ic}=a^ba^{ic}=a^b e^{\ln(a)ic}=a^b(\cos(c\ln a)+i\sin(c\ln a))$$

The geometric interpretation is that of a rotation of the vector $\langle a^b, 0\rangle$ by an angle of $c\ln a$.

Comment: Ohh okay that makes sense. I always thought that Euler's identity was derived from this formula, instead of the other way around. This makes much more sense. Thank you.

Comment: I think the most common common derivation of Euler's Identity comes from the Taylor Series expansions of $e^x$, $\sin x$, and $\cos x$

Comment: I will certainly look into that. Unfortunately, a lot of resources I find online try explaining it geometrically and kind of just tell you to take their word for it. I don't think I've ever seen it explained using Taylor Series expansions.